# How do I pass a value from one class to another without inheritance?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have two classes. the Main class is responsible for the main window in which the gif is played, and the Settings class represents a window in which you can select a gif. I need to pass the name of the gif selected in the Settings window so that it immediately starts playing in the Main window. How can I do this?

Part of the program related to this problem:

```
import sys
import traceback
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget


def except_hook(cls, exception, traceback):
    sys.__excepthook__(cls, exception, traceback)


class Settings(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.widget = QWidget()
        uic.loadUi('settings.ui', self)
        self.PB_OK.clicked.connect(self.close_this_window)
        self.all_gifs = ['cosmowave1.gif', 'cosmowave2', 'cosmowave3', 'retrowave1.gif', 'retrowave2.gif']
        self.CB_chooseGifs.addItems(self.all_gifs)

    def close_this_window(self):
        Main.gif = self.CB_chooseGifs.currentText()
        self.close()


class Main(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('mainWindow.ui', self)
        gif = 'cosmowave1.gif'
        self.gif_image = f'gifs/{gif}'
        self.settings_window = Settings()
        self.settings_PB.clicked.connect(self.settings)
        self.movie = QMovie(self)
        self.add_a_gif(self.gif_image)

    def add_a_gif(self, gif_image):
        self.movie.setFileName(gif_image)
        self.GIF_LBL.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.movie.start()

    def settings(self):
        self.settings_window.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.excepthook = except_hook
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Main()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your issue is just a matter of `connect`ing the correct event to the `add_a_gif function`. However, your example is not *complete*, so it's hard to help. For instance, what kind of widget is `self.CB_chooseGifs`? If it is a QListWidget, the interesting event would be `currentTextChanged`, and the solution as straightforward as adding this line: `self.settings_PB.currentTextChanged[str].connect(self.add_a_gif)`. So please, update your question with a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also, in your question, what do you mean by "immediately"? Is it "when the user clicks on the gif"? Or when the user clicks on the "Ok" button? Or when the secondary widget is closed?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar specifically with `PyQt5` but the usual technique for this sought of thing is to specify a "callback" function to be invoked when a certain event occurs, in this case when the settings windows is closed:

Modify the `Setttings` constructor to take such a *callback* argument and then modify method `close_this_window` to invoke the callback when it closes:

```py
class Settings(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, onclose):
        super().__init__()
        self.onclose = onclose
        ...

    def close_this_window(self):
        self.close()
        self.onclose(self.CB_chooseGifs.currentText())
```

Then the `Main` constructor just needs to construct the `Settings` instance as follows so that method `add_a_gif` is called when the settings window is closed:

```py
class Main(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ...
        self.settings_window = Settings(self.add_a_gif)
        ...
```

For a more general solution, investigate the *Observer Pattern*.